# Gauss Normal Map where $K\geq 0$

Tags: differential-geometry

> 1. Let $S$ be a compact connected surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with normal Gauss map given by $N$. Let $K$ denote the Gaussian curvature and $B_o^1=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3: |x|=1\}$. Prove that if $B=\{N(s): s\in S \:\text{ and } \: K(s)\geq 0\}$, we have: $$B=B_o(1)$$

**Attempt:** Clearly $ B\subset B_o(1)$ by the definiton of the Gauss map. To prove the other inclusion, suppouse $v\in B_o(1)$.

Let us take a coordinate system such that $v=(0,0,1)$. Take $\Phi: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be $\Phi(s)=s\cdot v$. Since $S$ is compact, a maximum must be attained in $s_o$. If $\alpha$ is a regular curve with $\alpha(0)=s_o$, we must have $\alpha'(0)\cdot v=0$, otherwise $\alpha'(0)\cdot e_3>0$ (or $<0$) and $\alpha(\epsilon)$ (or $\alpha(-\epsilon)$) ,for a small enough positive $\epsilon$, would have a larger third coordinate than $\Phi(s_o)$ (this contradicts the fact that $\Phi(s_o)$ is a maximum). Thus $v\cdot \alpha'(0)=0$ and $v=N(s_o)$.

$T_{s_o}S=\{x \cdot v=0\}$ and locally we are at the same side of the horizontal plane $s_o+T_{s_o}S$ (all points of $S$ are bellow or in it). If $K(s_o)<0$, we would have points in both sides of the plane, which is impossible. This means $K(s_o)\geq 0$ and $N(s_o)=v$, which implies $v\in B$. Therefore $B=B_o(1)$

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Just posting your homework for us to do is not appropriate. Moreover, we cannot be mind-readers and know what tools/knowledge you have.

Comment: @TedShifrin , I am clueless as to where to start. I would greatly value any tips. Assuming I am posting homework is very unflattering and it is not the case.

Comment: Clueless where to start? This looks like a great proof to me. The only issue is this: How do you know that $N(s_o) = v$ and not $-v$?

Comment: (By the way, I neither downvoted nor voted to close. I have now upvoted and voted to reopen.)

Comment: Please don't delete a perfectly fine question, especially if others have participated in helping.